# Parallel Diode in RC charging circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, digital-logic, diodes, clock, capacitor-charging

[image]

When button is pushed , active low RES pin is activated till Vc reaches 2.5 Volts. I have two questions  here 
1. What is the role of Diode which is connected reversed biased?
2. Which loop capacitor discharges when button is pushed ?

Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 0):

The diode is there so that when the supply switches off it discharges the capacitor C1 via the collapsing supply rail at the top of R3.

> *Which loop capacitor discharges when button is pushed ?*

C1 is discharged by the switch and ideally (to prevent large current spikes potentially upsetting the MCU) there should be a 100 ohm resistor in series with the switch.

Comment: ..unless you wanted to wet a silver alloy contact oxide used on switches rated for 2A + or really cheap junk , also you might choose a Schottky diode and use 10k in series with  RESET instead.